# Restler, writing test in behat for POST-Method

Tags: behat, restler

I want to write a TestScenario in Behat for a POST Method that takes an Object as input.

```
Feature: Testing The ChildController Endpoint

  Scenario: Trying to create an Child by POSTing vars with an existing Id
    Given that I want to make a new "Child"
    And the request is sent as JSON
    And its "screening_id" is "999888777666"
    And his "first_name" is "John"
    And his "last_name" is "Doe"
    And his "birth_date" is "1979-01-01"
    And his "gender" is "m"
    When I request "/v1/child"
    Then the response status code should be 409
    And the response should be JSON
    And the response has a "error" property
```

My Method is like:

```
/**
 * Child Endpoint v1
 *
 * @url POST child/
 * @status 201
 *
 * @param Child $child JSON data 
 * @return application/json
 * @throws RestException
 */
function insertChild(Child $child){......}
```

My JSON Object that I pass looks like this:

```
{
"child": {
    "screening_id": "",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "birth_date": "",
    "gender": ""
}
```

}

Now... when I make a request with Postman with only:

```
{
    "screening_id": "",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "birth_date": "",
    "gender": ""
}
```

it works fine. 
But when I'm running the Behat Test, it says that I specified an invalid value for 'child' and I get:

```
"error": {
      "code": 400,
      "message": "Bad Request: Invalid value specified for 'child'. Expecting an item of type `v1\\models\\Child`"
```

}

It works from everywhere without specifying the 'child' only from BeHat not.

Comment: Which version of Restler RC5 or RC6?

Comment: I'm using version 3 RC5

Answer (score 0):

**Solution is to change the order of things in your behat feature file**

> It works this way because of the way [`RestContext.php` bootstrap file](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/blob/master/features/bootstrap/RestContext.php) is defined.

Currently what you have and the test result

```
Feature: Testing The ChildController Endpoint

  Scenario: Trying to create an Child by POSTing vars with an existing Id # features/test.feature:3
    Given that I want to make a new "Child"                               # RestContext::thatIWantToMakeANew()
    And the request is sent as JSON                                       # RestContext::theRequestIsSentAsJson()
    And its "screening_id" is "999888777666"                              # RestContext::thatItsStringPropertyIs()
    And his "first_name" is "John"                                        # RestContext::thatItsStringPropertyIs()
    And his "last_name" is "Doe"                                          # RestContext::thatItsStringPropertyIs()
    And his "birth_date" is "1979-01-01"                                  # RestContext::thatItsStringPropertyIs()
    And his "gender" is "m"                                               # RestContext::thatItsStringPropertyIs()
    When I request "/v1/child"                                            # RestContext::iRequest()

|  POST /behat_test/v1/child HTTP/1.1
|  Host: localhost
|  User-Agent: Guzzle/3.1.2 curl/7.43.0 PHP/5.6.15
|  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
|  Content-Length: 2
|  
|  []
|  HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
|  Date: Sun, 20 Dec 2015 04:21:56 GMT
|  Server: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) PHP/5.5.30
|  X-Powered-By: Luracast Restler v3.0.0rc5
|  Vary: Accept
|  Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
|  Expires: 0
|  Content-Language: en
|  Content-Length: 468
|  Connection: close
|  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
|  
|  {
|      "error": {
|          "code": 400,
|          "message": "Bad Request: Invalid value specified for `child`. Expecting an item of type `Child`"
|      },
```

If you look closely the request is sending only an empty array

```
|  POST /behat_test/v1/child HTTP/1.1
|  Host: localhost
|  User-Agent: Guzzle/3.1.2 curl/7.43.0 PHP/5.6.15
|  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
|  Content-Length: 2
|  
|  []
```

Fix is to move `And the request is sent as JSON` below all property definitions. See below

```
Feature: Testing The ChildController Endpoint

  Scenario: Trying to create an Child by POSTing vars with an existing Id # features/test.feature:3
    Given that I want to make a new "Child"                               # RestContext::thatIWantToMakeANew()
    And its "screening_id" is "999888777666"                              # RestContext::thatItsStringPropertyIs()
    And his "first_name" is "John"                                        # RestContext::thatItsStringPropertyIs()
    And his "last_name" is "Doe"                                          # RestContext::thatItsStringPropertyIs()
    And his "birth_date" is "1979-01-01"                                  # RestContext::thatItsStringPropertyIs()
    And his "gender" is "m"                                               # RestContext::thatItsStringPropertyIs()
    And the request is sent as JSON                                       # RestContext::theRequestIsSentAsJson()
    When I request "/v1/child"                                            # RestContext::iRequest()

|  POST /behat_test/v1/child HTTP/1.1
|  Host: localhost
|  User-Agent: Guzzle/3.1.2 curl/7.43.0 PHP/5.6.15
|  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
|  Content-Length: 108
|  
|  {"screening_id":"999888777666","first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","birth_date":"1979-01-01","gender":"m"}
```

Comment: Then you should mark the question as answered and mark my answer as the right one